# Adding a user to a subscription model using a button on the show page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Wondering if you can help me here. Have been stuck on this for a while. I am trying to have a button on the course show page that will allow the current logged in user to show up as enrolled on that particular course. (Essentially just adding the user_id and course_id to the subscriptions model).

I might be going totally the wrong direction with this - I have a subscription model created which can take in the user_id and the course_id. I am trying to create an enroll class in the course controller that will allow the data named above to be entered into the subscriptions model. I didn't want to create a new subscriptions controller and work from there. Is it possible to just have a class defined in the courses controller that will grab the data and create it in the subscriptions model?

I can enter this data in manually using DB for SQlite program. I can then call this data of enrolled users and show in at the bottom of the course show page. My problem here is automating this addition using the enrol button. Any help would be appreciated. Code added.

Courses controller:

```
  def enroll
@subscription = Subscription.new(params[:current_user.id, :id])

@subscription.save
 end
```

private

```
def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(:title, :description, :price, :category_id, :course_img, :venue, :max_enrolment, :course_reference, :short_description, :duration_days, :duration_weeks, :start_date, :start_time, :end_date)
end
```

Routes code:

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/contact'

  devise_for :users
  resources :courses do
    post :enroll
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
```

Rake routes is showing this which looks good to me.

```
course_enroll POST   /courses/:course_id/enroll(.:format) courses#enroll
```

Show Page

```
<%= link_to "Enroll", course_enroll_path(@course), class: "btn-enroll" %>
```

Routing Error

```
No route matches [GET] "/courses/1/enroll"
```

Course model

```
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :subscriptions
```

User model

```
 has_many :courses
  has_many :subscriptions
```

Subscription model

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end
```

I understand it might require a GET action but what is the best way to go about this? or am I just going the totally wrong way trying to not make a subscriptions controller and just using the course controller for this. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the method within your `link_to` helper, because the default method will be `GET` unless the method is specified:

```
<%= link_to 'Enroll', course_enroll_path(@course), class: 'btn-enroll', method: :post %>
```

And I've noticed the way you're trying to create a new `subscription` within your enroll method will throw maybe another error, because for a new record you need the `course_id` and the `user_id`, but you're not sending the `current_user.id` and you're sending the whole `@course` object too.

I did this change in the `courses_controller` and worked successfully:

```
# app/controllers/courses_controller.rb
def enroll
  @subscription = Subscription.new(course_id: params[:course_id], user_id: params[:user_id])
  @subscription.save
end
```

Plus the edit in the params in order to create a new record:

```
<%= link_to 'Enroll', course_enroll_path(course, user_id: current_user.id), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastián. I never stopped to think about the method: :post and realising that the methods are done in an order on routes so wasn't picking up the method. I remember this from college. Thanks a million. 

Also nice one for the extra corrections I was fiddling away at them once I knew the subscription was been created but no sata was coming in. This explains a lot for me. Again thanks. Hero!

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Tried to mark it up vote but stackoverflow says if my level is not high enough the vote up gets recorded but is not shown publicly. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Ah yeah, to be honest I didn't even notice that was the accepted button. Don't be on this much but defo seeing it's value these days. Total newbie on here. Thanks Sebastian.